# Конкатенация значения макроса в командной строке

Tags: makefile, posix

В `sh` можно «конкатенировать» значения переменных таким образом:

```sh
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/johnsmith/local/bin"
```

Возможно ли что-то подобное при вызове `make`? То есть,
что-то типа такого (очевидно, не сработает, ибо рекурсия):

```
.POSIX:
.DEFAULT: out.bin

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

out.bin:
    echo $(PATH) > out.bin
```

```sh
$ make PATH='$(PATH):/home/johnsmith/local/bin'
```

Интересует портируемый `make`, то есть желательно без
*GNU*измов, если можно. Но если нельзя, тоже приму.

---

Один возможный вариант — пустой макрос:

```
.POSIX:
.DEFAULT: out.bin

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin$(EXTRAPATH)

out.bin:
    echo $(PATH) > out.bin
```

```sh
$ make EXTRAPATH=':/home/johnsmith/local/bin'
```

Этот вариант работает, но выглядит как-то не очень.

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял что требуется

Comment: В мейкфайле определён макрос. Надо из командной строки присоединить строку к этому макросу при вызове.

Comment: А зачем так? Обычно же наоборот типа `PATH := $(PATH):/bin:/usr/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала — цитата из стандарта [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_05):

> Macro definitions shall be taken from the following sources, in the following logical order, before the makefile(s) are read.
>
> 1. Macros specified on the make utility command line, in the order specified on the command line. It is unspecified whether the internal macros defined in Internal Macros are accepted from this source.
> 2. Macros defined by the MAKEFLAGS environment variable, in the order specified in the environment variable. It is unspecified whether the internal macros defined in Internal Macros are accepted from this source.
> 3. The contents of the environment, excluding the MAKEFLAGS and SHELL variables and including the variables with null values.
> 4. Macros defined in the inference rules built into make.
>
> Macro definitions from these sources shall not override macro definitions from a lower-numbered source. Macro definitions from a single source (for example, the make utility command line, the MAKEFLAGS environment variable, or the other environment variables) shall override previous macro definitions from the same source.
>
> Macros defined in the makefile(s) shall override macro definitions that occur before them in the makefile(s) and macro definitions from source 4. If the -e option is not specified, macros defined in the makefile(s) shall override macro definitions from source 3. **Macros defined in the makefile(s) shall not override macro definitions from source 1 or source 2**.

выделено мною: макросы, описанные в makefile, не должны переопределять макросы из источников 1 или 2.

т.е., макрос, указанный непосредственно в командной строке, имеет более высокий приоритет, чем описанный в makefile.

---

ну а теперь ответ на вопрос.

> Возможно ли что-то подобное при вызове make? То есть, что-то типа такого (очевидно, не сработает, ибо рекурсия)

рекурсивное определение можно указать непосредственно в командной строке:

```
$ make v:='$(v):что-то'
```

вот только значение макроса, указанного в makefile (смотрите цитату выше) не должно переопределять макрос, переданный в командной строке.

потому, если вы хотите сохранить значение макроса, присвоенное внутри makefile, вам не следует использовать то же самое имя макроса в командной строке. используйте другое имя, как и написали в вопросе.

---

пример, работающий одинаково и с *gnu/make*, и с *pmake*:

```
$ cat file
p=что-то$(a)
ku:
    @echo $(p)
$ make -f file a=':нечто'
что-то:нечто
$ pmake -f file a=':нечто'
что-то:нечто
```

Comment: только override нужен,  иначеmake игнорирует присвоения. А override, кажется, ГНУизм.

Comment: @Swift, дополнил примером.

Comment: так сработает )

Answer (score 2):

В GNU-make поодерживается директива override.

```
$ make FOO='blah'
```

makefile:

```
override FOO := blahblah, $(FOO)
```

Без `override` проигнорирует присвоение, что, если я не ошибаюсь, является гнуизмом. Портируемый способ требует задачи отдельной переменной. Соответсвенно в файле можно указать ее значение по умолчанию, а команда его заменит.